# Chrome - Javascript: Negative Exponent Calculation is wrong for > -3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8, exponent

I am working on React project.

I have use case where I have to add step attribute on Number `<Input>` tag. This step attribute will be dynamic. Based on array data.

Array data is `[{ precision: 2 }, { precision: 4 }, { precision: 5 }]`.

So I generate the step like:

```
<input type="number" step={ 10 ** -precision } >
```

Here `10 ** -precision` will output :

0.01  for precision = 2

0.0001 for precision = 4

0.00001 fror precision = 5

This is what I want, and it is working fine in Firefox and Opera.

But Chrome is the issue, Chrome's output for `10 ** -4` is `0.00009999999999999999`. Which is breaking in my case.

Chrome's output is correct till `10 ** -3` after that it is printing wrong.

[image]

My chrome version is : 74.0.3729.131 and OS: MacOs Mojave: 10.14.4

Comment: Using chrome, I get .0001 from 10 ** -4; perhaps you could just try Math.round(var);?

Comment: @Amy Not duplicate. That is not related to JS specifically. Every programming language output `0.1 + 0.2         ->  0.30000000000000004`

Comment: @shadoe2020 what is your chrome version? Mine is `74.0.3729.131`

Comment: 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @RahulSagore It doesn't need to be JS-specific to be a duplicate, considering that everything running on a computer follows the same IEEE-754 rules.  It does explain why this happens in JS.

Comment: @Amy Firefox and Opera calculating negative exponent correctly, Not on Chrome. While `0.1 + 0.2` is  calculating `0.30000000000000004` everywhere, it's known. This is chrome specific issue, on latest version.

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks, that is the correct duplicate. I could not find that question.

Comment: [Floating-Point Questions Are Endless on stackoverflow.com](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-questions-are-endless-on-stackoverflow-com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a floating point precision issue.
If you only have to pass it as prop to the  tag you can try
`<input type="number" step={ (10 ** -precision).toFixed(precision) } />`

Comment: Yeah this is possible solution. Will check and upvote. But the issue is really weird. Firefox and Opera outputting perfectly

Comment: I agree it's weird (also chromium works fine), and i cant quite explain it (js engine implementation? i dont know what to say). Let me know if the ```toFixed``` trick works